# sharepoint 2010 showing user names as lastname first name how to swap it?

Tags: workflow

i'm using SPD and the web interface.
And made a workflow to send an Email.
The first line in the email looks like:

Hello Clinton, Bill

But i would like to have:

Hello Bill Clinton

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the string concept in Designer. In the Designer workflow actions use "Utility actions", there you get 2 important options:

1. Extract sub string from the end of the string
2. Extract sub string from the start of the string

Hope this might solve your problem. But you haven't specified if the user name is in single field or there are multiple fields (e.g. First Name, Middle Name, Last Name).

Comment: this wont save your problem, in some countries first names can be 2, and lastnames can be combined, in dutch for example some last names are: van den xxxx,